# Spring Boot 2 Upgrade Issue: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property click found for type CampaignDetail

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

I have updated a Spring Boot project from version 1.5.3 to 2.0.3.RELEASE. Everything works fine when its deployed on Tomcat. 
Following exception occurs when this application is deployed on Wildfly server:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.gr.dm.core.repository.CampaignDetailRepository.getCampaignSummaryByClick(java.util.Date,java.util.Date)! No property click found for type CampaignDetail! Did you mean 'clicks'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Here is the code for CampaignDetailRepository.java:

```
public interface CampaignDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<CampaignDetail, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<CampaignSummaryDto> getCampaignSummaryByClick(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);

}
```

And CampaignDetail.java:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CampaignDetail.campaignSummaryMapping", classes ={
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = CampaignSummaryDto.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "source", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "cost", type = Double.class),)}) })

@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "CampaignDetail.getCampaignSummaryByClick", query = NativeQueries.CAMPAIGN_SUMMARY_BY_CLICK, resultSetMapping = "CampaignDetail.campaignSummaryMapping")})

public class CampaignDetail implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String campaignId;...
```

I understand that the default query lookup strategy of Spring Data JPA is `CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND` but in case of native query, shouldn't it be using the provided query in entity class?

I am not sure why spring is trying to create a query by method name for a method annotated with nativeQuery = true. 
Same application works fine in Tomcat but throws exception when being deployed on Wildfly 9.

Comment: Please add the `CampaignDetail` codes, from the exception, there is no `click` property in `CampaignDetail`.

Comment: I know that there is no `click` property in `CampaignDetail`. As you can see in `getCampaignSummaryByClick` method in `CampaignDetailRepository` class, i have set `nativeQuery = true` and added a native query in `CampaignDetail` class for this method. Then why is Spring trying to create a query based on the method name? Also, like i mentioned earlier, this piece of code works fine when deployed to Tomcat.